# JetBrains $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Tags: go

Very simple code is not working. Can't find what's problem.
In console no one request didn't work. Because I dont know how use go-terminal in console. Maybe I can change some settings?

go.mod contains module "awesomeProject"

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("some text")
}
```

GOROOT=C:\Users\olli\sdk\go1.16.3 #gosetup

GOPATH=D:\Projects\GoLang #gosetup

C:\Users\olli\sdk\go1.16.3\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\olli\AppData\Local\Temp___go_build_awesomeProject.exe awesomeProject #gosetup

$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Compilation finished with exit code 1

UPD:
I didn't fix the problem, just erased it and installed everything in the base folders, without changing it, and everything worked.

Comment: C:\Users\olli\sdk\go1.16.3 is not the standard installation path. Just follow https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started

Answer (score -1):

try to initialize the module with;

```
go mod init awesomeProject
```